# From r data.frame into asp.net GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, r, gridview, r.net

I'm using RdotNet library for calling R functionalities into asp.net and I have the following data frame from r:

```
DataFrame dataset = engine.Evaluate("string1").AsDataFrame();
engine.SetSymbol("dataset", dataset);
```

Is there any solution, how can I fill my GridView (gvMainPage) by this data? Thanks a lot for any of you suggestion. I really spent a lot of time on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find complete example of using R with .NET: http://www.r-bloggers.com/importing-and-displaying-a-data-frame-with-c-and-r-net/. I adopted this solution to the ASP.NET gridview:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < dataset.ColumnCount; ++i)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dataset.ColumnNames[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < dataset.RowCount; ++i)
{
    var row = dt.NewRow();

    for (int k = 0; k < dataset.ColumnCount; ++k)
    {
        row[dataset.ColumnNames[k]] = dataset[i, k];
    }

    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}

myGridView.DataSource = dt;
myGridView.DataBind();
```

And here is my gridview declaration:

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I know this approach, winforms DataGridView is very different than asp.net GridView. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: @SmithiM I updated my answer to provide you a way to use GridView.

Comment: got it... I had my gridview outside div and now works fine, thanks a lot.